# What convention is correct to retrieve a list of MongoDb documents asynchronously?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asynchronous

I've come across two different ways to retrieve a list of MongoDB documents asynchronously. One is suggested by MongoDB, and another is something I've got implemented currently.

1) Suggested by MongoDB:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync()
{
    return await _collection.Find(x => true).ToListAsync();
}
```

2) A method I have currently:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync()
{
    var result = await _collection.FindAsync(x => true);
    return await result.ToListAsync();
}
```

What would the difference be here?
Is the first way really async? Isn't it retrieving using `Find()` synchronously then asynchronously returning a list?

Some insight on this would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Find` is not a finished operation, it just creates a query object for finding objects that you can use to add more search parameters in a fluent manner.

Your second approach will return a [`IAsyncCursor`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IAsyncCursor_1.htm) which allows you to asynchronously iterate over the collection, but it won't let you add more search arguments to the call.

So to answer your question: both ways are asynchronous, they're just two different ways of searching for-, and returning a document.

See the methods found on [`IFindFluent`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IFindFluent_2.htm) (returned by a call to [`Find`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_Find__1.htm)) and on [`IAsyncCursor`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IAsyncCursor_1.htm) (returned by a call to [`FindAsync`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_FindAsync__1.htm)).

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense.